# GAE log on localhost to file

Tags: google-app-engine

when i debug my GAE application on localhost, how can i save the log created with Logger class to file? I can see it in console now(stderr) but dont want to redirct console to file. I found some solutions for python but cant make it work for java. Please can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Add an ApplicationAppender in your log.xml setting file:

```
<appender name="applicationAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
    <param name="encoding" value="UTF-8"/>
    <param name="file" value="C:/logs/yourlogname.log"/>
    <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{HH:mm:ss} %-5p %l - %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>
```

This is for log4j, but it is a standard logging paradigm. Also you need to have your logger definition use the appender you create.

Comment: This probably won't work on App Engine, since it prevents you from writing to the local filesystem.

Comment: Even though its the local development server? I understand what your saying, but it seems like a silly constraint on the dev server side of things.

Comment: The dev_appserver attempts to emulate the production environment as closely as possible, that includes prohibiting writing to files.

Answer (score 0):

In Linux and OSX, you can use `tee` to direct output to a file while still making it visible on standard out:

```
my_command | tee filename
```